# Which permission is required to listen for the `onInstalled` event on Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

```js
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function(details) {
    chrome.tabs.create({ url: "chrome://extensions/?options=(extensionId)" });
});
```

I want to guide users to the extension's option. Previously, I was only using the "storage" permission.

I want to listen to the `onInstalled` event and create a new tab. Is there any other permission required to do this?

Comment: Please elaborate on what you mean by this: "I want to guide users to extension's option and previously I was only using "storage" permission."

Comment: Previously, it was functioning OK only with storage permission. Now I'm going to update the extension, and when updated, I want to show option tab to users. So I added a listener above, and curious about any permission is needed to execute the listener

Comment: No need for any permission.